# Run single application in Wayland without full desktop

Tags: 22.04, wayland, kiosk

I am setting up a kiosk using Ubuntu server 22.04 that only runs a Web Browser.
Do I need to install the full desktop environment to achieve this or is there a way I can run only FireFox?

Previously I would consider running a minimal x desktop but I'd like to stick with Wayland if possible and it might have a better solution.

Comment: [Ubuntu Frame](https://mir-server.io/ubuntu-frame/), the successor to mir-kiosk, is designed specifically for kiosk-type use on Ubuntu. It comes as a snap.